# How do I fix a "Could not resolve hostname" Error in juju status?

Tags: server, juju, maas

I have my nodes in ready and one node in allocated to root stage , now when i bootstrap it gives success but when i do juju status it gives an error as below :

```
juju bootstrap
2012-08-15 21:32:34,449 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2012-08-15 21:32:34,636 INFO juju environment previously bootstrapped.
2012-08-15 21:32:34,637 INFO 'bootstrap' command finished successfully 

juju status 
2012-08-15 21:33:17,833 INFO Connecting to environment... 
2012-08-15 21:33:23,013 ERROR Invalid host for SSH forwarding: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node-000c29d63ebb.local: Name or service not known
2012-08-15 21:33:53,166 ERROR Invalid host for SSH forwarding: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node-000c29d63ebb.local: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things wrong here:

1. You have no DNS entry for hostname node-000c29d63ebb.local, which is what
   the default node name is when using the enlistment process. You can cheat by
   putting it in /etc/hosts
2. You only left a minute between starting the bootstrap and doing the status.
   This step can take **30-60 minutes** depending on the hardware of the node which
   is being bootstrapped (it installs a new OS on it).

So, make that hostname resolvable and then wait for the bootstrap to finish.

Comment: This helped me. In /etc/resolv.conf can  use the domain this way: search domain.net